# How do i change the colours of visual studio? [New user]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, highlight

Im currently a C++ student in uni. I started using visual studio code configurated by a friend and then i changed to visual studio 2022 (the community version).

In visual studio code the code looks prrety much like this:
[image: How it looks in visual studio code]

Then in visual studio it looks like this:
[image: How it looks in visual studio]

Does anyone know how to change the highlighted or at least can give me a hint? thanks!

I tried looking in the settings on visual studio but i got confused since there are many options and i dont know exactly what to change

Comment: In visual studio ... Then in visual studio - I don't understand

Comment: In the big Options dialog, look under Environment->Fonts and Colors. There *are* hundreds of items to color, like "C++ Keyword". Select that item and change from Magenta to Blue (or whatever you like). Will take a while to sort out everything...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [Visual Studio Theme Pack extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idex.vsthemepack), which brings the default VS code themes to VS. Also see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/custom-themes/) for other converted popular VS code themes, and [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/vs-code-themes-in-vs/) which describes a tool to convert any VS code theme.

Regarding the colored (rainbow) braces, there is [the "Rainbow Braces" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.RainbowBraces) (corresponding [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/adding-color-to-bracket-pairs/)).
For further configuration, you might also want to have a look at the [Visfora extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomasRestrepo.Viasfora), which also includes rainbow braces.

Extensions aside, many of the colors can also be manually and individually configured in the Visual Studio's options → Environment → Fonts and Colors.